# Can a person enter the UK on a EU family member visa without their spouse?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration

My husband got visa for UK as a EU family member but I am already in UK. Could he enter UK while I will wait for him at UK airport ?

Comment: Yes, that's fine...

Comment: Assuming you are the EU citizen, you must either be in the UK or traveling with your husband.  You are already in the UK, so all is well.  If the border officers doubt your husband for some reason, they might try to make contact with you, to verify your presence in the UK.  So don't be too surprised if that happens, but don't worry too much about it.

Answer (score 4):

EU freedom of movement also entails having the right to join one's spouse in another EU country so since you are already in the UK, the family permit definitely covers this situation, even if you do not cross the border together. The [official website](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eligibility) reflects this:

> The EEA citizen you’re joining must either:
>
> - be in the UK already
> - be travelling with you to the UK within 6 months of the date of your application

Things would be different if your husband went to the UK before you or wanted to visit the country alone but that's not the case here. Because of this, knowing your address and contact details (to be able to show you are a resident) might be useful (although I have no idea whether and how often people are actually challenged about this in practice).